# How to Select SQL for XML with fixed head line

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a simple SQL table with Values "`Alpha`", "`Bravo`" and "`Charlie`".

I Need to get result as displayed. The data within transaction: `type`, `date`, etc. are static and should be part of the select Statement.

I think this can be done using

> SELECT ... for XML

But don't know how?

[image: Input]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SampleTable]([ID_extern] [varchar](50) NULL)    
INSERT INTO SampleTable VALUES ('Alpha')   
INSERT INTO SampleTable VALUES ('Bravo')
INSERT INTO SampleTable VALUES ('Charlie')
INSERT INTO SampleTable VALUES ('Delta')
```

[image: Desired Result]

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots. It makes it so much harder for people to get started on an answer. Tables should preferably be given as `CREATE TABLE` / `INSERT` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little kick-start for you

**Example**

```
Select [transaction/@type]='import_serial_number'
      ,[transaction/@date]='123459'
      ,[transaction/@vaultname]='Type in the name of the vault here'
      ,[transaction/serial_number/@name]  = 'SampleAppendSerialNo'
      ,[transaction/serial_number/@mode]  = 'append'
      ,[transaction/serial_number] = (
                                      Select [serno_item/@item_counter] = row_number() over (order by ID_extern)
                                            ,[serno_item/@serno_item] = ID_extern
                                       From  SampleTable
                                        For  XML Path (''),TYPE
                                      )
For XML Path('transactions'),Root('xml')
```

**Returns**

```
<xml>
  <transactions>
    <transaction type="import_serial_number" date="123459" vaultname="Type in the name of the vault here">
      <serial_number name="SampleAppendSerialNo" mode="append">
        <serno_item item_counter="1" serno_item="Alpha" />
        <serno_item item_counter="2" serno_item="Bravo" />
        <serno_item item_counter="3" serno_item="Charlie" />
        <serno_item item_counter="4" serno_item="Delta" />
      </serial_number>
    </transaction>
  </transactions>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where a column value goes in the XML is determined by a path in an alias. Use `@` for attributes. To get the ordinals you can use `row_number()`.

Something like

```
    SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id_extern) "serno_item/@item_counter",
           id_extern "serno_item/@item_value"
           FROM simple
           FOR XML PATH ('');
```

gives you the inner part of the XML. You can either try nested queries or use string concatenation (`concat()`) to prepend/append the outer parts like in the following.

```
SELECT convert(xml, concat('<serial_number type="">',
                           (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id_extern) "serno_item/@item_counter",
                                   id_extern "serno_item/@item_value"
                                   FROM simple
                                   FOR XML PATH ('')),
                           '</serial_number>'));
```

(I'm not going to type all that stuff off of your screen shot, so this is just exemplary.)